# Javascript Node js return type of a function is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The following code gets the data from MONGODB

```
function getCategory(){
    Category.find((err,categories)=>{
        console.log(categories);    //prints categories object 
        return categories;     
    })
}
function getPages(){
    Page.find({}).sort({sorting:1}).exec((err,pages)=>{
        console.log(pages);    //prints pages object
        return pages;
    })
}
```

but when i try to get their values they are returning undefined instead of returning categories and pages object

```
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(getCategory());    //undefined
    console.log(getPages());       //undefined
}
```

i tried returning outside the callback from getCategory() but still undefined

```
function getCategory(){
    let t= {} ; 
      Category.find((err,categories)=>{
         t= categories;
     })
     return t;
}
```

can please someone explain the reason ?

this might be due to async calling i don't know ? Thanks

Comment: look *closely* at the functions ... the return statements are inside a callback - there is no return directly from the functions you have return, therefore, they return `undefined` - it's not due to `async` - though, that **is** an issue you'll need to tackle, it's due to actually not returning anything

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks but how can i get categories in routes

Comment: `return Category.find(...`

Comment: Promise { <pending> }
undefined this is what i am getting

Comment: Your second attempt is a classic example of erroneously trying to return a value from an asynchronous function. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/20625681).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `{}` to Category and a callback function to the getter methods

```
function getCategory(callback){
    Category.find({}, (err,categories)=>{
        console.log(categories);    //prints categories object 
        callback(err, categories);  
    })
}
function getPages(callback){
    Page.find({}, { sort: { sorting: 1 } }, (err,pages)=>{
        console.log(pages);    //prints pages object
        callback(err, pages);
    })
}

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    getCategory((err, category) => {
        console.log(category)
    })
    getPages((err, pages) => {
        console.log(pages)
    })
}
```

Or as a promise

```
function getCategory() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Category.find({}, (err,categories)=>{
            console.log(categories);    //prints categories object 
            resolve(categories);  
        })
    })
}
function getPages() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Page.find({}, { sort: { sorting: 1 } }, (err, pages)=>{
            console.log(pages);
            resolve(pages);
        })
    })
}

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    getCategory().then((category) => {
        console.log(category)
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
    getPages().then((pages) => {
        console.log(pages)
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```